# how to fix error "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API" in xml file google maps?

Tags: android

i was try use this link to get direction "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=10.933952,106.863352&destination=10.9490721,106.8574901&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=wailing&metric=1" but today it not working

please help me!!

```
<DirectionsResponse>
  <status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status>
<error_message>
  You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.
</error_message>
</DirectionsResponse>
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Slaks. i want fix error "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.".

Comment: Did you add the API Key?
<google api url here>?key=MY_SERVER_KEY
Sometimes, with a misconfigured API Key, it tends to give an API Limit error. 
If you did add the right key, then you reached you daily quota, which is about 25k requests / day since I've last checked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#limitexceeded

> You can exceed the Google Maps API Web Services usage limits by:
>
> ```
> Sending too many requests per day.
> Sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.
> Sending requests too fast for too long or otherwise abusing the web service.
> Exceeding other usage limits, e.g. points per request in the Elevation API.
> ```

Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but I am using the google place/autocomplete and there is a reason to be call the api on each keyboard key press. and yes the api can be called twice/thrice in a sec some times. 
Also please tell what do you mean by too many requests (in number)

Comment: @QadirHussain, I have the same problem. Any fix?