# Google Place API Usage Limit Error

Tags: angular, google-places-api

I am developing a web app in Angular6. I activated my Google Place API account yesterday. I used it via `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` plugin. After successful integration, many times I getting following error with HTTP status 200:

"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."

This is little weird, since my quota is too high with $200 credit. I searched on internet/SO, I found that rate of request also matters. Thus I checked my metrics in my Google account:
[image]

From the screenshot its clear that I am not exceeding the daily quota and also my rate of request per second is also low. But still I get this error.

Can someone please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216519/you-have-exceeded-your-daily-request-quota-for-this-api-google-places-api-ios-s

Comment: I already checked this one. Even if try querying through postman keeping few minutes gap i get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved after carefully following these instructions:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors

> API Key and Billing Errors
>
> A darkened map, or ‘negative’ Street View
> image, watermarked with ￼“for development purposes only” is returned
> when any of the following is true:

- > The request is missing an API key.
- > Billing has not been enabled on your account.
- > The provided billing method is invalid (for example an expired credit card).
- > A self-imposed daily limit has been exceeded.

In my case, I was using API key of a Google project whose billing was not enabled.